# Проверка подключения к интернету на JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Приветствую всех! Делаю приложение на основе **HTML5 + CSS3 + JS**. Запуск сего приложения начинается со страницы выбора языка, но так как приложение подразумевает связь с новостной лентой, и отправки информации от пользователя создателю, мне необходимо ограничить доступ к главной странице в случае отсутствия подключения к сети. Возможно ли при помощи **JS** проверить подключение к интернету?

Comment: сделать запрос и если получил ошибку - подключения нет

Comment: Это я понимаю! Запрос к чему необходимо выполнить? Подключается ли к ленте или...?

Comment: Да, вполне можно добавить обработчик ошибки подключения к новостной ленте

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотел добавить, что для ваших целей можно воспользоваться готовым решением. Например [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) можно использовать как простую библиотеку или же заодно использовать встроенную функциональность для показа сообщения об отсутствии подключения. Также в упомянутой либе есть приятная особенность — она умеет перехватывать все ваши запросы на сервер, и если один из них возвращает ошибку, то она сразу извещает вас об этом + начинает кешировать все запросы на сервер. Таким образом, когда подключение починится, оно сумеет заново послать все ваши запросы на сервер (конечно, это можно и отключить при необходимости).

А что касается самостоятельной проверки — на мой взгляд не стоит проверять доступность Гугла, если вам нужна доступность вашего сайта. Проверяйте лучше подключение, посылая запросы на какой-нибудь favicon вашего сайта. Таким образом вы не просто проверите, что интернет есть, но и то, что ваш сайт не упал.

Answer (score 2):

Отправьте GET запрос к *google.com* , в теле коллбека для теста можно просто вывести что-нибудь в консоль.

```
var req = ({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://google.com'
});

$http(req).then(function successCallback(successData){
//при удачном 
},function errorCallback(errorData){
//при ошибке
});
```

Comment: А если гугл ляжет? Или закроется вообще?

Comment: поэтому я и обращаюсь к google, по-моему такое просто невозможно, но по теории вероятности - шанс хоть и маленький, но есть. Я ответил первое что пришло в голову, а как решить такую проблему, чуточку выше человек уже сказал что для данного решения прекрасно подойдет (http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)