# Проверка наличия интернет соединения html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница html (лендинг) весит в локалке, не у всех пользователей есть интернет, нужно сделать что то вроде проверки есть соединение у пользователя или нет, к примеру если есть у человека интернет то на этой html странице в определнном месте выводится картинка подключение есть, если нет то др. картинка с надписью подключение отсутствует.

Comment: Мне кажется с помощью HTML этого нельзя сделать. Нужно подключать JS. Я плохо знаю js, попробуйте добавить тег javascript может кто и подскажет. И еще попробуйте посмотреть вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515803/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно  попробовать показать какую-либо картинку и если она не загружается, значит соединения нет.
Рекомендую поменять ссылку на какую-либо другую картинку.

```html
<div id="test"></div>

  <script>
    function doConnectFunction() {
      console.log("connection");
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature">';
    }

    function doNotConnectFunction() {
      document.getElementById("test").innerText = "Интернета нет!";
    }

    var i = new Image();
    i.onload = doConnectFunction;
    i.onerror = doNotConnectFunction;
    //Поменяйте ссылку на любую другую
    i.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f2c24d6cdf719af1599d800078f5b880?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' + escape(Date());
  </script>
```

Можно проверить через условие

`{i.onload ? doConnectFunction():doNotConnectFunction()}`

Как вариант предлагаю рассматривать не `innerHTML` а просто поменять пути у картинки.

Comment: дело в том что если интернета нет, то открывается "затычка" с инфой что нет интернета, НО любой скрипт видит эту "затычку" так что интернет есть! И соответсвенно пишет что коннект ОК или выводит нужную картинку что всё ок.

Comment: @АлександрКаракозов Если я вас правильно понял, можно проверить через условие. Ответ дополнил.

Comment: Не силен в яве, можно поподробнее? Использовал скрипт отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515803/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js но этот скрипт так же видит что интернета нет, получает заглушку и думает что это интернет и показывает что соединение есть.

Comment: @АлександрКаракозов а как он показывает что соединение есть?
Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Так пробовали?

```js
navigator.onLine ? console.log("Есть интернет") : console.log("Нет интернета")
```

Comment: нет, это где именно или к какому скрипту?

Comment: @АлександрКаракозов, к какому скрипту? В смысле? В файле `script.js` (или какой там у Вас) делаете эту проверку и если есть интернет соединение, то делаете то, что Вам нужно, если же нет, то делаете другое действие...